Loud whistle noise from aio fans under load
When under load such as when doing demanding tasks on my pc, my aio (Corsair H100x) fans make a really loud whistling noise.

my CPU temps are still very good though, around sub 70 degrees celsius. The reason im asking for help is because  the sound is very loud, i hear them in my noise cancelling headphones. I cant attach an audio here because only images are allowed but its very annoying.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Have the fans always made this noise? Whistling could be caused by where the fans are installed, something coming in between the fans and the air space between the next object (either on the intake or outlet side of the fans), a defect or damage to the fan shroud, etc.

Could also be that the air moves against the memory, and that it is shaped like a flute. A whistle kind of noise, means that air is vibrating another object extremely quickly. Normal fan movement would not do that. It is possible a bearing is causing the fanblade itself to start vibrating. Given there are 2 blades, I would turn off the pc, make sure it is cold, then make one of the blades not moving, and turn on the pc and do a short stress test that would normally produce the sound. Then quickly turn off the computer for it to cool down again and test the other blade if you heard the noise.

this noise does not exist when the pc is on a low-load such as browsing the internet. only when im doing very demanding tasks, such as playing an aaa game or render things, does it start. it goes away when the task is not being performed.and by visual cues i can confirm that it is not touching the memory. and it did not always do this, it only started recently. i noticed it especially today, where it was really loud. the fans are exhaust fans, by the way.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d5IbbW-OBO0 not my video, but it sounds similar to this, albeit only under load

You will need to determine where it is the AIRFLOW causing the whistle (more likely) or the HARDWARE (less likely). Change the airflow using your hand or something else and see if the whistle changes. It is remains consistent no matter what you do to the airflow, it is the hardware making the noise and you'll likely just need to replace the hardware. If it is airflow, start by cleaning, make sure there is enough clear vents to allow air INTO the case and OUT of the case.
